# Insert row in another table when insert in first table by trigger?

Tags: triggers, oracle10g, multiple-tables

I am trying to insert one row every time in `stud_report` table whenever I insert row in `stud_master` table. for that I have tried following SQL code with the help of triggers but I am getting:

> Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg
      AFTER INSERT ON stud_master
     FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
      roll number;
      sum number;
      per decimal(5,2);
   BEGIN
        roll := stud_master.roll_no;
        sum :=  stud_master.sub1+stud_master.sub2+stud_master.sub3;
        per := (0.33*(sum));
        insert into stud_report values (roll,sum,per);
   END;
   /
```

Stud_master table contains

```
+---------+--------------+----------+
| Field   | Type         | Null?    |
+---------+--------------+----------+
| roll_no | number       | NOT NULL |
| name    | varchar2(15) |          |
| sub1    | number       |          |
| sub2    | number       |          |
| sub3    | number       |          |
| Address | varchar2(30) |          |    
+---------+--------------+----------+
```

Stud_report table contains

```
+------------+--------------+----------+
| Field      | Type         | Null?    |
+------------+--------------+----------+
| roll_no    | number       | NOT NULL |
| total      | number       |          |
| percentage | decimal(5,2) |          |
+------------+--------------+----------+
```

Compilation errors are:

> 8/26     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
>            following:
>            (
>   9/49     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the
>            following:
>            (
>   10/7     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
>            one of the following:
>            ;

Comment: I think you should set a delimiter. Please post the compilation errors as well.

Comment: Number is not a mysql data type. Are you using oracle?

Comment: yes i am using Oracle Database 10G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not that far away - use :new instead of the table name (and I would avoid using sum as a variable name)

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER trg
      AFTER INSERT 
      ON STUD_MASTER
     FOR EACH ROW

     DECLARE roll NUMBER;
       sumNO NUMBER;
       per decimal(5,2);
    BEGIN
        roll :=  :new.roll_no;
        sumNO:=  :new.sub1+:new.sub2+:new.sub3;
        per  := (0.33*(sumNO));
        --dbms_output.put_line('New roll no '|| roll || ' sum = ' || sumno || ' PER = ' || per);
        insert into stud_report  values (roll,sumNO,per);
   END ;
   /
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My trigger is created successfully but now when i am inserting row in `Stud_master` i am getting an error  ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.TRGIN' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: Hmm.. I tested it and it worked fine for me. Can you show me your insert statement?

Comment: `insert into stud_master values (141,'David',73,85,91,'Washington');`

Comment: The error seems to relate to a trigger called TRGIN can you check if this exists and either fix or delete it if it does.